# Is it possible to open an Apple Developer account for a client?

Tags: iphone, ipad

My company is developing an iPad app for a technically unsophisticated government client, and I understand that they need their own Apple Developer account.  We would like to open and maintain the developer account for them, because we'll be much happier to have the control of our own destiny, and they'll be much happier to delegate the work to us.

But in the [Apple Enrollment Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enrollment.html), it says this:

> **I'm a contractor who develops apps for companies other than my own.
>   How do I ensure my  client's name is listed as the “Seller” on the App
>   Store?**
>
> If your client plans to distribute the apps you create for them on the
>   App Store  with their legal entity name as the “Seller”, they must
>   enroll in the iOS Developer Program. They can add you as a member of
>   their development team so you can access the resources you need to
>   create the app. While they must be the one who submits the app for
>   review, you can assist them if necessary.

This makes it sound like any company that wants to be a "Seller" must physically create their own account and do at least some of the work, even when it's clear that another party is the only one that is going to be able to do any of the work.  Am I reading this right?  Is it really not possible for a contractor to set up a developer account on behalf of a client?

Comment: Sounds like it would be the easiest if they created the account and then gave you access to it (i.e. by giving you the password of *their* account).

Comment: See my question for @MishieMoo below; easiest is not our goal here, we're getting paid to do the hard work on behalf of the client, but are we allowed to?

Comment: @Anonymous: why the downvote?  What on Earth could be wrong with this question?!

Comment: I have read the FAQ very carefully and fail to see how this question is off topic for SO.  To me it is very clearly a "practical, answerable problem that is unique to the programming profession". Does this mean that you can't ask a question about software development if it deals with the business side of the profession?  Where *would* I be allowed to ask this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is correct. Your client is responsible for creating an account and paying the developer fee.

<strike>You could create the account, but then when your contract is over you would be getting support requests, be responsible for all future updates, and have to renew the account every year. It's better for your client to create the account.</strike> **SEE EDIT**

---

**Edit:** Found a thread on this discussion - http://www.buzztouch.com/forum/thread.php?tid=10608297F86BD057C74C0F9. The post by MGoBlue on 10/10/11 at 09:04 PM is Apple's stance, which says not to do that. Don't mess with Apple, have your client create an account and invite you to it.

There's also a note about this on [Apple's Program Enrollment FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enrollment.html):

**I'm a contractor who develops apps for companies other than my own. How do I ensure my client's name is listed as the “Seller” on the App Store?**

> If your client plans to distribute the apps you create for them on the App Store with their legal entity name as the “Seller”, they must enroll in the iOS Developer Program. They can add you as a member of their development team so you can access the resources you need to create the app. While they must be the one who submits the app for review, you can assist them if necessary.

Comment: I get that about the hassle associated with being the account creator, but in this case the client wants to pay us to take responsibility for this kind of hassle.  So maybe this is semantics, but does that mean that we can, within the rules, create the account, pay the fee, say that our name is the seller, and be the contact for the account?

Comment: There's some special legalese surrounding this kind of behavior. See this thread - http://www.buzztouch.com/forum/thread.php?tid=10608297F86BD057C74C0F9, specifically the post at 10/10/11 09:04 PM by MGoBlue, where Apple basically said don't do that.